# Conversion failed when converting date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have googled and haven't found any that matches my case.

```
declare @from_ datetime, @to_ datetime
SET @from_ = '2013-01-01' 
SET @to_ = '2013-10-01' 

DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(4000) 
SET @query = N'
DECLARE @from datetime, @to datetime
SET @from = CAST('''+@from_+''' AS datetime)
SET @to = CAST('''+@to_+''' AS datetime)
'
```

Gives error:

```
  Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 34
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

The `SET @query = N'` is Line 34

I have also tried with `CONVERT(datetime, '+@from_+', 102)` with and without `, 102)` and `'''`

and with just

```
SET @from = CAST('+@from_+' AS datetime)
```

Same result

Solution is part of a PIVOT, so I have the declare, select, pivot and execute @query. The rest of the solution works nicely, until I bring the datetime into play.

Comment: Why are you adding extra quotes around @from_ and @to_?  That's probably the cause of your issue.

Comment: How about where it says "And with just" .. and the "Same result"?

Comment: Even with the and with just, you are still adding extra things around it, like '+ and +' so that won't work either.  The variables with the underscores be declared as varchar, and the ones without as the datetime?  See t-clausen.dk's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are adding a datetime with a varchar. Try this instead:

```
declare @from_ char(8), @to_ char(8)
SET @from_ = '20130101' 
SET @to_ = '20131001' 

DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(4000) 
SET @query = N'
DECLARE @from datetime, @to datetime
SET @from = CAST('''+@from_+''' AS datetime)
SET @to = CAST('''+@to_+''' AS datetime)
'
```

Comment: Hmm, that solves the conversion issue, now I need to find out why it doesn't match any data. One step closer (I think). Ah doh - my bad.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I guess you have appended apostrophe(') to `@from_` and to `@to_`

```
SET @from = CAST('''+@from_+''' AS datetime)
SET @to = CAST('''+@to_+''' AS datetime)
```

Also why are you not directly setting the values like this

```
SET @from = @from_
SET @to = @to_
```

Comment: Because it is part of a PIVOT, as per - http://stackoverflow.com/a/14440162/185084

Comment: ok. I'll see if I find it (or any other solution) running at my end.

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this

```
declare @from_ NVARCHAR(50), @to_ NVARCHAR(50)
SET @from_ = '2013-01-01' 
SET @to_ = '2013-10-01' 

DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(4000) 
SET @query = N'
DECLARE @from datetime, @to datetime
SET @from = CAST('''+@from_+''' AS datetime)
SET @to = CAST('''+@to_+''' AS datetime)'
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```